# Thinktecture in windows azure web sites SSL issue

Tags: azure, thinktecture-ident-server

I have deployed the thinktecture identity server in the windows azure website role.The issue I am facing is with the SSL certificate.If I don't have a custom domain name I am forced to use *.azurewebsites which already have a certificate from microsoft and the app pool account is not able to read the private key of this certificate so it's throwing an error.

Did someone have the same issue or any ideas about what I can do to resolve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SSL and signing certificate don't need to be the same. Use the MS SSL cert (for now) and generate a separate cert for signatures. That cert can then be uploaded so that you can programmatically access it.

Comment: So I uploaded the cert but ThinkTecture does not see it at all .The code Thinktecture uses for getting the certificate is from Local Machine which is not supported in Azure Website.Any workaround for this.

Comment: I see in this post you weer saying that the support will be added for azure websites https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/53  .Do you know of any workaround to make this work.

Comment: OK - I misread your question - you use the word "role" so I thought "Web Role" - but yes you are right v2 is not compatible with web sites due to the absence of a certificate store. You can write custom code in the ConfigurationRepository to load the cert from an alernative location.